# How to declare a fix bytes type more than bytes32?

Tags: solidity, bytes

I am facing "**UnimplementedFeatureError: Nested dynamic arrays not implemented here.**
" when I try to emit an event contains bytes [] data;

I have a fix size of data which is 65bytes but there is no supported type to put it in. so I use a dynamic bytes.

I have this event:

```
event SkillValidated(
        address indexed user,
        address [] validators,
        bytes [] signatures, //a signature is a 65 bytes
    );
```

when I emit the event I got the mentionned error. 
and when I change it to:

```
event SkillValidated(
        address indexed user,
        address [] validators,
        bytes32 [] signatures, // I lost part of signature
    );
```

it works!

How can I resolve the problem, have I to implement a specific type using struct?

Answer (score 1):

Just use bytes is already a dynamic type (array of byte). In the way you declared is like you created a nested array.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html

Comment: and what is the solution ?

Comment: Using just bytes doesn't work?

Comment: what you mean by "just bytes" ? I already using bytes and doesn't work

Comment: You're using an array of bytes. Remove [] since bytes is already an array and writing bytes[] is equal to byte[][]. While bytes is byte[]. The error seems to tell that nested array are not allowed.

Comment: I need an array of bytes not of byte. every signature is a 65bytes

Comment: An array of byte is dynamic, means it can contains as much byte as you wish. Bytes express an array of byte (actually is even better because it will not waste space). Can you please read the documentation?  In some extent bytes can be considered same as string (but it doesn't need to be utf8 compliant). If you need to send more than one signature you can just concat all the signature in one and read it in chunk of 65 bytes from your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string type instead of bytes32.

Comment: `string` are expected to be utf8 compliant not very well suited for a signature (raw 65 bytes).

Comment: strings are a dynamic arrays also